# How do I trigger an event from pasting in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am trying to take the text from clipboard, split it into an array and create a new row in the datagrid for each element in the array. However, I am having difficulty getting the method to trigger. Like so:

```
void delivGrid_Keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.V &&
            (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
               
            string clipData = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText();
            string[] clipRows = Regex.Split(clipData, @"\r");
            foreach (var row in clipRows)
            {
                delivGrid.Items.Add(new Deliverable { name = String.Empty, desc = row, rDays = String.Empty });
            }
            //viewModel.Paste()
        }
    }
```

I haven't been able to find anything on a paste event for a WPF Datagrid. Does anybody know of a way that I could trigger this event for to intercept the pasting?

Answer (score 2):

You could check [DataObject.AddPastingHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataobject.addpastinghandler?view=netcore-3.1) which allow you to define a handler to the pasting event like shown [here](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/pasting-handler/) for a TextBox.

The problem is that the pasting event only happen when it the control already accepts it:
For a DataGrid, it will only happen when you attempt to paste an editable cell which is not what you are trying to achieve.

I think you should create a CustomControl inheriting from a control accepting paste directly (a TextBox for example), but you will have to recreate some of the dependency of a DataGrid (for the itemsSource for exemple).

I set up a small demo so that you can check the different behaviors:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--Simple DataGrid-->
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MaxWidth="150" Grid.Column="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Col1" Binding="{Binding Path=BusinessItem1}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Col2" Binding="{Binding Path=BusinessItem2}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <!--TextBox (so that we can use the copy paste functionnality) modified to show a dataGrid-->
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxButActuallyReallyADataGrid" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <DataGrid MinHeight="250" Margin="10" Background="LightBlue" MinWidth="250" x:Name="DataGridForDemoCustomControl" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CustomCol1" Binding="{Binding Path=BusinessItem1}"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CusomCol2" Binding="{Binding Path=BusinessItem2}"/>
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                                </DataGrid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
    
    <!--To show the default behavior on a real textBox-->
    <TextBox x:Name="TestTexBox" Text="Default_Text" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Since it is a demo, I didn't create a ViewModel nor the Bindings but I recommand doing it
        this.GetData();
        this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = this.MyData;
        //Add an handler to the pasting event for the specified dataObject
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataobject.addpastinghandler?view=netcore-3.1
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this.DataGrid, PasteHandler);
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(TextBoxButActuallyReallyADataGrid, PasteHandlerForTemplatedTextBox);
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(TestTexBox, PasteHandlerForTextBox);
    }

    private void PasteHandlerForTextBox(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textbox && e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }

    }

    private void PasteHandlerForTemplatedTextBox(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox dataGrid && e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }

    }

    private void PasteHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGrid dataGrid && e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
            
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            MyData.Add(new MyRowElement { BusinessItem1 = "text1_" + i.ToString(), BusinessItem2 = "text2_" + i.ToString() });
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyRowElement> MyData { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyRowElement>();
}

public class MyRowElement
{
    public string BusinessItem1 { get; set; }

    public string BusinessItem2 { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to create a CustomControl you could do it like in my exemple but you won't be able to access the dataGrid by name in codeBehind.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed response! If I'm unable to access the dataGrid by name, how do I manipulate the data to be displayed? I'm imagining I set the ItemsSource to the textbox?

Comment: If you use MVVM you can simply do a Binding from the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to the property containing the data in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle the `PreviewKeyDown` something like this:

```
delivGrid.PreviewKeyDown += (ss, ee) => 
{
    if (ee.Key == Key.V && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.R)))
    {
        //...

        //escape default behaviour:
        ee.Handled = true;
    }
};
```